# Android - how can a Fragment be (completely) destroyed upon orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I am a beginner with Android and I have been experimenting with Fragments. I understand that upon orientation changes Fragments are re-created every time. How do I prevent this from happening, i.e how do I 'completely' destroy (I apologize for the loose terminology) a Fragment that previously existed in one of the orientation modes from re-creating in the other?

Comment: Would you elaborate? You want the fragment to not show up after you changed orientation?
or, you don't want fragment to recreate? just show what fragment you have without destroying but with new orientation?

Comment: If I get it right, you want to [detach](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach(android.app.Fragment)) the Fragment if an orientation change happens?

Comment: @SteveBenett Yes, that is exactly what I would like to do.